# Copy and Paste a selection based on LastRow

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I am just trying to copy and paste a selection from one worksheet into the first blank row of another master worksheet. I plan to do this with a few different worksheets, but I can't understand why I keep getting an error message.

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sht3 As Worksheet
Dim shape As Excel.shape

Set wsmaster = Sheets("Sheet 1")
Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet 2")
Set sht3 = Sheets("Sheet 3")

LR = wsmaster.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
NR = wsmaster.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

With ThisWorkbook
sht2.Range("A:AI").Copy
wsmaster.Range("A" & NR).PasteSpecial Paste:=pastevalues
End With
```

Comment: What error message and on which line?

Comment: Run time error '1004': application defined or object defined error. It occurs on the pasting line. I have tried different variations of this to no avail. I have confirmed that it does work in selecting the correct cell, it will not paste though.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see is that you are trying to copy a range of columns `Range("A:AI")` into a cell `Range("A" & NR)`.

You can also improve your code

1. Define `wsmaster` (I'm guessing it used to be `sht1`)
2. Remove `LR` as it is not being used
3. Remove the `With Thisworkbook` wrapper as it is not needed

Comment: How would I paste into the worksheet using last row then? With this report I know that I will need columns A:AI, but the lastrow may change. As for the remaining variables they are used in the complete project, but I am only having trouble with this part.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to copy? Your code indicates you are copying entire columns, not row based data.

Comment: The range would be A1:AI65523. I used the column format to capture the entire set without having to reference lastrow because the lastrow may change the next time I have to pull this report. I can use sht2.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR, 35)).Select to select the range I want, but how would I paste it into the first available row of the master worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out

```
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
NR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

sht2.Activate
sht2.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR, 35)).Copy
sht1.Activate
sht1.Range("A" & NR).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```